# Notepad++ - "Replace with" adds new-line character after replaced text. How do I remove it?

Tags: notepad++

Original text:

```
2###
Test 123
```

I am doing this operation:

```
Find what: 2###
Replace with: 2###\r\nText before
```

Result:

```
2###
Text before
Test 123
```

Desired result:

```
2###
Text before Test 123
```

For some reason it adds a new-line after the replaced text. It seem to only happen when I add \r\n or \n in the Replace with.

How can I set it up so it does not insert this newline?

Comment: +1 for question in the form of: Input, program(sure, you could call it a program), output, expected output.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Line 1 is actually `2###<new line>`.

You are replacing `2###` with `2###<newline>Text before`, making the line (in effect) into `2###<newline>Text before<newline>`.

You need to include the new line you want to replace in your search.

Find: `2###\r\n`
Replace with: `2###\r\nText before`